# SQL query to find first event of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a SQL query on our door system database to see what time everybody gets to work. At the moment I'm am just using the statement

```
Where DATEPART(hh, ev.dEvent_Date) between '5' and '10'
```

to limit the results to between 5am and 10am but John Smith might have gone outside to receive something or for a break so the report will have multiple entries for a person on one day. Is there a way I can get the first event for everyone each day? My current query is below

```
Select tFirstName as FirstName
    ,tLastName as LastName
    ,DATENAME(dw, ev.dEvent_Date) as [Day]
    ,CONVERT(varChar(11),ev.dEvent_Date) as [Date]
    ,CONVERT(varchar(2) ,DatePart(hh,devent_Date))+':'+ case when len(convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n,devent_Date))) = '1' then '0'+ convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n,devent_Date))else convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n,devent_Date)) end as [Time]

From dbo.tblevents as ev, dbo.tblEmployees as em
Where DATEPART(hh, ev.dEvent_Date) between '5' and '10'

AND ev.dEvent_Date between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))-1), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate())) and DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))
And em.iEmployeeNum = ev.iUserNum
AND tByte6 = 11
AND tByte8 = 22
Order by LastName, [Date]
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't just use a `MIN(time)` and aggregate by `DAY`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for all days.  And simplify your query a bit:

```
Select tFirstName as FirstName, tLastName as LastName, DATENAME(dw, ev.dEvent_Date) as [Day]
        CONVERT(varChar(11), ev.dEvent_Date) as [Date],
        (CONVERT(varchar(2) , DatePart(hh, min(devent_Date)))+':'+
         case when len(convert(varchar(5), DatePart(n, min(devent_Date)))) = '1'
             then '0'+ convert(varchar(5), DatePart(n, min(devent_Date)))
             else convert(varchar(5), DatePart(n, min(devent_Date)))
         end
        ) as [Time]
From dbo.tblevents ev join
     dbo.tblEmployees em
     on em.iEmployeeNum = ev.iUserNum
Where ev.dEvent_Date between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))-1), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate())) and
                             DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate())) And 
tByte6 = 11 and tByte8 = 22
group by tFirstName, tLastName, cast(dv.dEvent_Date as date), DATENAME(dw, ev.dEvent_Date)
Order by LastName, [Date];
```

To be honest, would use the following to get the date and time formatted as a single column:

```
convert(varchar(16), min(ev.dEvent_date), 121);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Grouping and get MIN of the dEvent_Date:

```
Select tFirstName as FirstName
,tLastName as LastName
,DATENAME(dw, MIN(ev.dEvent_Date)) as [Day]
,CONVERT(varChar(11), MIN(ev.dEvent_Date)) as [Date]
,CONVERT(varchar(2) ,DatePart(hh, MIN(devent_Date)))+':'+ case when len(convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n, MIN(devent_Date)))) = '1' then '0'+ convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n, MIN(devent_Date)))else convert(varchar(5),DatePart(n, MIN(devent_Date))) end as [Time]

From dbo.tblevents as ev, dbo.tblEmployees as em
Where DATEPART(hh, ev.dEvent_Date) between '5' and '10'
AND ev.dEvent_Date between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))-1), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate())) 
AND DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))), DATEADD(ww, -1, getdate()))
AND em.iEmployeeNum = ev.iUserNum
AND tByte6 = 11
AND tByte8 = 22
GROUP BY tFirstName, tLastName
Order by LastName, [Date]
```